# Как проверить, если запущенна ли функция?

Tags: javascript

Господа, есть функция ***window.onscroll*** она запускается и если документ проскролен больше 200px то она запускает ***countRun()*** , а если меньше то 
***countStop()***

```js
var p1 = document.querySelector('.p1');
var p2 = document.querySelector('.p2');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var count = 0;
var run;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  p1.innerHTML = scrolled;
  if (scrolled > 200) {
    countRun();
  } else {
    countStop();
  }
}

function countRun() {
  run = setInterval(function() {
    p2.innerHTML = count++;
  }, 1000)
}

function countStop() {
  count = 0;
  clearInterval(run);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  perspective: 100px;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
}

.p1 {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.p2 {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  top: 70px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p class="p1">0</p>
  <p class="p2">0</p>
</div>
```

Но как видно  в примере, все работает не так хотелось бы. Догадываюсь, что в условии еще и надо проверить, если ***countRun()*** запущен и не запускать его больше, ну или что-то другое о чем я не догадываюсь...

Comment: Возможно вам нужно проверять, не запущенна ли **функция**, а запущен ли **интервал**?
При инициализации интервала `run` с `undefined` измениться на id интервала. Собственно вот и решение, `if (run)` проверит запущен ли Ваш интервал. **Однако**, при сбросе интервала `run` нужно явно привести к `undefined`. `clearInterval(run); run = undefined;`

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, нет, в том то и дело, что в функции countRun(), могло бы производиться другое действие... меня интересует как проверить запущена ли сама функция countRun();...  А что там твориться это уже важно...  И без флажка...

Comment: Ваша функция выполняется долю секунды, как вы хотите успеть проверить что в данный конкретный момент она запущена?) А вот если проверять запущен ли интервал, это гарантирует что функция выполнила хотя бы один раз.

Comment: Небольшое логическое дополнение. JS **синхронный** язык. То есть одна конкретная функция работает в один конкретный момент времени. соответственно одновременной проверки работы функции и собственно работы самой функции **быть не может**

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, понятие "запущенности" можно ещё распространить на стек вызовов..

Comment: @VasiliyRusin, благодарю я понял о чем ты...

Comment: @vp_arth, браузеры дают доступ к call stack? Если да, пожалуйста дайте ссылку на информацию, очень интересно будет почитать.

Air, оформлю ответом, на будущее. Уверен вопрос достаточно популярный.

Comment: Доступ не доступ, я просто формально поправил, что в данный конкретный момент можно считать, что работает не одна функция, а все вложенные вызовы. Из нестандартного api, есть `Function.prototype.caller`

Comment: @vp_arth,  Как мало я еще знаю....

Comment: @vp_arth, допустим, но это скорее очень плохой подход, которым мне кажется в крайнем случае лучше пользоваться на серверах, а не на front-end. В любом случае я понял что вы хотели сказать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверить "запущена ли функция" невозможно. Можно проверить, "была ли запущена функция". Для этого функция сама должна себя где-то регистрировать.

В вашем случае, есть несколько решений. Первое, в лоб - нужно просто сбрасывать интервал, если счётчик уже был запущен. Второе, что почти то же самое, обнулять переменную run, и по ней определять, "была ли запущена функция".

```js
var p1 = document.querySelector('.p1');
var p2 = document.querySelector('.p2');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var count = 0;
var run;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  p1.innerHTML = scrolled;
  if (scrolled > 200) {
    countRun();
  } else {
    countStop();
  }
}

function countRun() {
  if (run) return;
  // или 
  // if (run) clearInterval(run);
  run = setInterval(function() {
    p2.innerHTML = count++;
  }, 1000)
}

function countStop() {
  count = 0;
  clearInterval(run);
  run = false;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  perspective: 100px;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
}

.p1 {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.p2 {
  position: sticky;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  top: 70px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p class="p1">0</p>
  <p class="p2">0</p>
</div>
```

---

Вариации на тему:

```js
var p1 = document.querySelector('.p1');
var p2 = document.querySelector('.p2');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

class Counter {
  constructor(el, period = 1000) {
    this._el = el;
    this._period = period;

    this._run = false;
    this.clear();
  }
  clear() {
    this._el.innerText = this.counter = 0;
  }
  inc() {
    this._el.innerText = ++this.counter;
  }
  start() {
    if (this._run) return false;
    this._run = setInterval(() => this.inc(), this._period);
  }
  stop() {
    if (this._run) clearInterval(this._run);
    this._run = false;
    this.clear();
  }
}
let counter = new Counter(p2, 500);

window.onscroll = function() {
  let scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  p1.innerText = scrolled;

  if (scrolled > 200) {
    counter.start();
  } else {
    counter.stop();
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  perspective: 100px;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.p1 {
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}

.p2 {
  left: 25px;
  top: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p class="sticky p1">0</p>
  <p class="sticky p2">0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Только еще в countStop() надо что-то дописать, а то он выполняется без остановки если < 200 =)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, это уже условие...  Это щас не важно)))

Comment: vp_arth,  Ну не совсем то...  Ты пойми, что я хочу знать запущена ли сама функция countRun()...  А что в ней творится уже не важно...

Comment: @Air Подскажите мне, если не трудно, я не очень понимаю,  данный пример чем-то отличается от моего флага и если да, то чем? Это я спрашиваю не с издевкой, а для самообучения. Насколько я понимаю, тут тот же флаг, только проверка вынесена в функции, да? А запущена ли функция, получается, правда невозможно проверить. Ведь пока она выполняется, только она и работает, тут же нет нескольких потоков...

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов,  да ты прав, ни чем не отличается, но vp_arth думаю лучше прокомментирует, так как я тоже не опытен,  vp_arth опытнее и меня и тебя...

Comment: @Air, код в этом ответе не важен. Ответ в первом абзаце.  Максим, пример отличается архитектурно. Ты возлагаешь ответственность за проверку повторного запуска на клиентский код, у меня это выполнено более системно. Сама по себе практика очистки интервала перед потерей его дескриптора - просто обязана присутсвовать.

Comment: @vp_arth понятно, спасибо!

Comment: @Air, и что значит проверить запущена ли функция? Функция countRun выполняется синхронно, оставляя в eventLoop зарегистрированный интервал, который будет запускаться вне контекста функции countRun.

Comment: @vp_arth, будь другом, глянь. и в моем примере и в твоем, count  не обнуляется сразу, а после того как запускается заново...  не соображу почему?

Comment: @vp_arth,  все понял, обнуояется, мы его в параграф не записываем)))  все ок...)))

Answer (score 2):

По идее да, нужно добавить условие (работает, вроде бы, как нужно):

```
var isRun = false;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  p1.innerHTML = scrolled;

  if (scrolled > 200) {
    if(!isRun) {
      countRun(); 
      isRun = true;
    }
  } else {
    if(isRun){
      countStop();    
      isRun = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Максим Степанов, твой ответ спасает ситуацию, но со всем уважением, не отвечает на вопрос. Флажок я и сам сообразил использовать.. Просто  в примере его нет...  Меня именно интересует, как проверить запущена ли на данный момент функция, если это возможно...  Но плюс я тебе поставлю за смекалку)))))

Comment: @Air спасибо, я предполагал подобное =) может, лучше удалить ответ, чтобы кто-то написал про функцию все-таки? Как по-другому проверить, запущена ли функция, я тоже не знаю, интересно было бы...

Comment: Не надо удалять,  каждый ответ хорош собой, тем более, что тебе его оценили уже двое положительно...  И то что ты так ответил моя вина, я должен был это отметить в вопросе...  Так что ответ оставь...  Он тоже несет в себе ценность

Comment: И тем более, я лично не знаю, есть ли возможность проверить запущенна ли функция.. А если нет? То твой ответ приму как правильный))

Comment: Вообще, насколько я понимаю, функция `countRun() ` то уже не выполняется, а выполняется `setInterval(function() {  p2.innerHTML = count++;  }, 1000)` ... Только выполнение его можно проверить, сама функция уже завершила работу по идее.

Answer (score 2):

*Это большой комментарий для наглядности*

У вас на самом деле не один таймер создается, а целая куча. Добавил в ваш пример вывод номеров таймеров. Причина в том, что `onscroll` выполняется много раз с в течение прокрутки. Можно, например, складывать номера таймеров в массив и массово зачищать интервал, либо проверять есть ли уже таймер (и делать `clearInterval` для него) перед созданием нового.

```js
var p1 = document.querySelector('.p1');
var p2 = document.querySelector('.p2');
var p3 = document.querySelector('.x1');
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var count = 0;
var run;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  p1.innerHTML = scrolled;
  if (scrolled > 200) {
    countRun();
  } else {
    countStop();
  }
}

function countRun() {
  run = setInterval(function() {
    p2.innerHTML = count++;
  }, 1000);
  p3.innerHTML += ', ' + run;
}

function countStop() {
  count = 0;
  clearInterval(run);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #272727;
  perspective: 100px;
  color: white;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300%;
}

.p1, .p2, .p3 {
  position: sticky;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.p2 {
  top: 70px;
}

.p3 {
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p class="p1">0</p>
  <p class="p2">0</p>
  <p class="p3">Timer IDs: <span class="x1"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Я в курсе, что он многократно запускает функцию countRun();

Comment: @Air это большой комментарий для наглядности, как лучше поступить с лишними таймерами вам решать.

Comment: Ну да))))  комментарий и в прям  не маленький)))

Answer (score 1):

### Краткий ответ: нет. Но в этом и нет необходимости из-за спецификации языка.

JavaScript синхронный язык (не путать с асинхронным программированием). В один конкретный момент времени - выполняется одна конкретная функция. Соответственно проверять запущенная ли функция невозможно, она либо еще не запущена, либо уже выполнена.

#### Лучшее решение данной проблемы на мой взгляд

```
var run;
```

При инициализации `run` `undefined`
Затем, когда мы инициализируем интервал, run передается его id.

```
run = setInterval(function(){console.log('text')}, 1000);
```

Сейчас run равно например `28`
Соответственно мы можем проверить и тот факт что функция выполнилась и тот факт что сейчас у нас запущен интервал. Например так:

```
if (run) {};
```

При очистке интервала необходимо снова сбросить `run` в `undefined`, **`clearInterval` не сделает этого автоматически**

```
clearInterval(run);
run = undefined;
```

Теперь мы знаем что интервал не запущен.